# DDD design concept

Tags: domain-driven-design

I have a class called FileConverter that takes as input a doc file and returns as output a docx file. What concept does the FileConverter represents in a DDD design.

Is it an entity or a service? Or is it something else?

Comment: It's nothing. You don't need DDD for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep your domain focused. A FileConverter is likely something that doesn't live in your domain but at the outside - it's a technical concern.

Comment: Why do you assume the FileConverter is not part of the domain. Can't a product owner understand the concept and ask for specific conversion of files using a FileConverter?

Comment: Does a product owner understand what a database table is? ;) It's hard for me to imagine a File Converter living very close to your _business_.

Comment: Well, as strange as it might seem, the Product Owner doesn't know about a database table but asks for a File Conversion.

Comment: Would you say the FileConverter is part of your business process?

Comment: I'm saying a FileConverter is part of the domain model when you are building an application that is processing files.